# c1xx : fatal error C1023 unexpected error with pch

Tags: visual-studio-2005, pch

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 team suite sp1 on Windows 7 sp1. That error will appear when I compile my project after I restart my computer.

The detail error message : "c1xx : fatal error C1023: 'projectname.pch' : unexpected error with pch, try rebuilding the pch"

Here's some meet the same problem :

[Fatal Error C1023](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b99f6ef2-c89b-46f5-9966-55837ad8672b/fatal-error-c1023-unexpected-error-with-pch-try-rebuilding-the-pch-and-administrator-rights?forum=vcgeneral)

He fixed the problem by removing the /Zm compiler option. But I have to use that option because my PCH file is too large.

Here is [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397190/visual-c-precompiled-headers-errors).

I tryed, but it doesn't work. After that change, the difference is that the same error will appear lot of times during one build.

and here ["Visual C++ Precompiled Header Errors on Windows 7"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/11/12/visual-c-precompiled-header-errors-on-windows-7.aspx?PageIndex=1#comments), seems like it is the same reason as mine, but there's no patch for visual studio 2005.

So, I need your help, I can't fix it by myself. 
Thanks !